# One page of the application goes infinte reload angular

Tags: html, angularjs

Index.html

```
<base href="/" />
```

RouteConfig

```
angular.module('DFApp').config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/Home", {
        templateUrl: "../Views/ListofTopicsDiscussed.html",
        controller: "ListofTopicsDiscussedController"
    })
      .when("/ShowParticularTopic", {
          templateUrl: "ShowParticularTopic.html",
          controller: "ShowParticularTopicController"
      })
        .when("/Topics/:TopicID", {
            templateUrl: "../Views/ShowParticularTopic.html",
            controller: "ListofTopicsDiscussedController"
        })
       .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Home" });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

From **Home** to **Topic** I navigate using this link

```
<a href="Topics/{{topic.TopicID}}">{{topic.TopicName}}</a>
```

Also I have tried adding the $loction.path in my Controllers which didnt help me. Please help me with a solution for this.

Comment: Check if you are using the controller on page (html) also.

Comment: Not really related but you should never use expressions in `href`. You can use `ng-href` though.